# XPM and translate using multiple content masters

Tags: experience-manager, translation-manager, blueprint

I'm know that in order for XPM to show the Translate option the context repository of the page/component you're editing needs to have some translation configuration defined.

But in a multiple content masters scenario [(as shown in the docs)](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-CEDF4C19-E3C9-4CA3-8D7B-FF206B98CCEA&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-9626D6F9-477B-4639-9B5E-8E5FD4FCA4D5.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-CEDF4C19-E3C9-4CA3-8D7B-FF206B98CCEA) - if you have the BluePrint context of XPM  for your EN website set so components are created in your global English (EN) Content publication - then you can't translate from within XPM as this publication has no translation configuration - you have to localise at the translation layer English Translation publication - is that right?

[image]